# Select option doesnt bind with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object with AllCountries and SelectedCoutry.
I want to list all countries on a `<select>` and select the option with ng-model by the value of SelectedCountry.

But the default value of combobox gets selected null.

Example:

```js
angular.module('ngPatternExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.OBJ = {
                    "OBJ": {
                      "AllCountries": [
                        {
                          "country": "USA",
                          "id": 1
                        },
                        {
                          "country": "Mexico",
                          "id": 2
                        },
                        {
                          "country": "Canada",
                          "id": 3
                        }
                      ],
                      "SelectedCountry": {
                        "country_id": 1,
                      }
                    }
                }
                
      $scope.AM = $scope.OBJ.OBJ;
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="ngPatternExample">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  selected country: {{AM.SelectedCountry.country_id}} <br/>
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="AM.SelectedCountry.country_id">
    <option value=""> --- </option>
    <option ng-repeat="co in AM.AllCountries" value="{{co.id}}"> {{co.country}} </option>
  </select>
</div>
  </body>
```

(http://plnkr.co/edit/PI3tOrIMSTMwGC0rYA5q?p=preview)

p.s A good explanation why this doesnt work allways in Angular would be great

Comment: Post the relevant code here at SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your select with this

```
<select class="form-control"  ng-options="co.id as co.country for co in OBJ.OBJ.AllCountries" ng-model="AM.SelectedCountry.country_id">
    <option value=""> --- </option>
</select>
```

Comment: @user3334406 I've replaced your `select` in the Plunker with what Hassan Tariq suggested, it works fine.

Comment: Remove ng-repeat from options

Comment: OK this works now :) thanks a lot, can someone explain why ng-repeat doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

Use `ngOptions` directive instead of repeating options in the select box by yourself.

```
<select 
  class="form-control"
  ng-model="AM.SelectedCountry.country_id"
  ng-options="co.id as co.country for co in AM.AllCountries">
    <option value=""> --- </option>
</select>
```

Updated plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FZcJVkJQlbLM3k544s8S?p=preview